# Show attendance submission links according to date and status

Tags: php, date

I have a list of dates in my database for submitting attendance, which is done weekly.
I want to use the dates to generate a link, so that a teacher can click on that date link to submit attendance for that week. I just need to know what's the best way to go about it. Once they have submitted the data, I want that week's link to not be clickable. The main thing here is that the dates/links show up in a specific time frame--say 3 days maximum past the end of week date.

Comment: not yet once i know which route to take i'll start coding. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your SQL query, you'll probably want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

I'm going out on a limb and assuming you're using MySQL.

See this for more date/time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: thanks Jason but i have already set the dates in the db and would want to be able to somehow check the current date and then show the date that is closest to the current date. i don't want to have to hard code any dates. thanks

Comment: Just played around with this and it is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks ;)